# SQL Update 2 different columns with similar table(not the same columns) from different database (same server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i update 2different columns using the data of similar table(not the same column) from another database (same server), the below query works fine for one column how can i alter the same query for 2 column update.

```
update pdldb.items
set opening_value = t.clsbal 
from [pdldb16-17].items as t
where pdldb.items.id=t.id
```

the 2nd column update should be

```
cls=t.op_stk
```

Comment: You can use update pdldb.items
set opening_value= t.clsbal , cls=t.op_stk
from [pdldb16-17}.items as t
where pdldb.items.id=t.id; Hope this is what you need. If not make your question clear

Comment: Thanks works fine. @JimMacaulay

Comment: Cannot work fine on SQL server, there are at least 2 syntax errors in that query. instead `[pdldb16-17}.items` it should be `[pdldb16-17].dbo.items`, right?

Comment: sorry, for the typo @VojtěchDohnal

Comment: Have posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,

```
update i
set opening_value = t.clsbal 
    ,cls = t.op_stk
from pdldb.items i
inner join [pdldb16-17]..items t on i.id=t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution ,

```
update pdldb.items set opening_value= t.clsbal , cls=t.op_stk from [pdldb16-17}.items as t where pdldb.items.id=t.id;
```